# Problem with app center

Tags: appcenter

[image]

App center shows that is 5 updates. But when I push to update, I see information: Waiting for package manager lock 
After while updating ends and I am on the start. I see 5 updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have another install process running. Do you have another package manager like Synaptic running? if nothing else is running try a reboot. Also try updating from the terminal rather than the app center: sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

Comment: Thank you!!!  sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade solved my problem